# running a react native project on android

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I've followed exactly the official tutorial on how to configure RN environment [this one](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup), every thing seems to be good, but when i created a simple project and tried to run it by `react-native run-android` i got this error

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
7 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 5 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-linux Daemon #0: AAPT2 is not supported on 32-bit Linux, see supported systems on https://developer.android.com/studio#system-requirements-a-namerequirementsa

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-linux Daemon #1: AAPT2 is not supported on 32-bit Linux, see supported systems on https://developer.android.com/studio#system-requirements-a-namerequirementsa

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-linux Daemon #3: AAPT2 is not supported on 32-bit Linux, see supported systems on https://developer.android.com/studio#system-requirements-a-namerequirementsa

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-linux Daemon #2: AAPT2 is not supported on 32-bit Linux, see supported systems on https://developer.android.com/studio#system-requirements-a-namerequirementsa

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-linux Daemon #4: AAPT2 is not supported on 32-bit Linux, see supported systems on https://developer.android.com/studio#system-requirements-a-namerequirementsa

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-linux Daemon #5: AAPT2 is not supported on 32-bit Linux, see supported systems on https://developer.android.com/studio#system-requirements-a-namerequirementsa

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-linux Daemon #7: AAPT2 is not supported on 32-bit Linux, see supported systems on https://developer.android.com/studio#system-requirements-a-namerequirementsa

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-linux Daemon #6: AAPT2 is not supported on 32-bit Linux, see supported systems on https://developer.android.com/studio#system-requirements-a-namerequirementsa


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

I did some research and all i found is that the linux os is not compatible, but in my case i have a 64 bit linux, here is my `lcpu` result

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               142
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7300U CPU @ 2.60GHz
Stepping:            9
CPU MHz:             2625.481
CPU max MHz:         3500.0000
CPU min MHz:         400.0000
BogoMIPS:            5399.81
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
```

Knowing that my laptop is a company laptop, does that may be the problem ? i have the sudo access though

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of struggling time i found out that i was using a `jdk` for 32bit

You can check which version of `jdk` you have by running `java -d32 -version` you should have an error if your jdk is 64 bit

So i just installed a 64bit jdk and every thing is working just fine now